# How to add a UIImageView to a UIView without displaying the content of the UIImageView that is outside of the UIViewBorder

Tags: ios, objective-c, animation, uiview, uiimageview

I am trying to add a UIImageView to a UIView, the problem is that the image view is outside of the UIViews frame, so theoretically it should be hidden (the part of the UIImageView that is situated outside of the UIView).

Here is my code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    firstRectangle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
    firstRectangle.hidden = NO;
    firstRectangle.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    [self.view addSubview:firstRectangle];
    [firstRectangle setContentMode:UIViewControllerHierarchyInconsistencyException];

    secondRectangle = [[UIImageView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0,  -[[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
    secondRectangle.hidden = NO;
    secondRectangle.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    [firstRectangle addSubview:secondRectangle];

    UIButton *animateButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height/2, 100, 30)];
    animateButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [animateButton addTarget:self action:@selector(animateButtonFunction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:animateButton];
}

- (void)animateButtonFunction{

[UIView animateWithDuration:10.f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveEaseOut
                 animations:^{

                     [firstRectangle setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
                     [secondRectangle setFrame:CGRectMake(0,  0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL completed) {



                 }];

 }
```

Answer (score -1):

Fixed all the problem, here is the code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad {
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.

    firstRectangle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
    firstRectangle.hidden = NO;
    firstRectangle.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
    firstRectangle.bounds = CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height);
    firstRectangle.clipsToBounds = YES;
    [self.view addSubview:firstRectangle];

    secondRectangle = [[UIView alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
    secondRectangle.hidden = NO;
    secondRectangle.backgroundColor = [UIColor redColor];
    secondRectangle.layer.borderWidth = 5.f;
    secondRectangle.layer.borderColor = [[UIColor greenColor] CGColor];
    [firstRectangle addSubview:secondRectangle];

    UIButton *animateButton = [[UIButton alloc]initWithFrame:CGRectMake([[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width/2, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height/2, 100, 30)];
    animateButton.backgroundColor = [UIColor greenColor];
    [animateButton addTarget:self action:@selector(animateButtonFunction) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
    [self.view addSubview:animateButton];
}

- (void)animateButtonFunction{
NSLog(@"test");
[UIView animateWithDuration:.6f
                      delay:0.0f
                    options:UIViewAnimationOptionCurveLinear
                 animations:^{

                     [firstRectangle setBounds:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];
                     [firstRectangle setFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height)];

                 }
                 completion:^(BOOL completed) {



                 }];

}
```

- one of the problem was that I needed to add the clipToBounds and Bounds properties to my code.
- then I just tweaked the code to obtain the wished animation, I hope these code will help others in implementing transition or different animation.